# Office Communicator - View Previous Conversation Grayed Out

Tags: office-communicator-2007

I cannot select my 'View Previous Conversation' option when I right+click a contact. I have enabled the option to 'Select my instant message conversations in the Outlook Conversation History folder' in Tools->Personal. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Note that this was working previously for the past year. When I logged into my machine earlier, I've noticed that the option of seeing other previous conversations have been disabled.

Looking at my Conversation History folder in Outlook, I do see that I have a lot of conversations saved, however, none of these are from today. I just had a conversation with a co-worker, and Communicator displayed a message saying that this conversation has been saved. Looking into the Conversation History folder, I cannot find this saved conversation. Perhaps Communicator cannot save the conversation in Outlook for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my issue by restarting both Outlook and Communicator.

Comment: If this was the answer to your question, please accept it as the answer.